# IPv6 Address Switch

Tags: python, linux, shell, ip, ipv6

I have IPv6 addresses on a Linux based server. How can I switch the current address to a new one? Is there a way to do it using shell commands? How about using Python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy: `ip -6 address add 2001:dead:beef::2/64 dev eth0`.

The same goes for removal: `ip -6 address delete 2001:dead:beef::1/64 dev eth0`

To show your addresses: `ip -6 address show`

Comment: Thank you very much! If I have anymore trouble, I know who to contact!